# How to write a simple function to combine all these similar codes?

Tags: r, lapply

There are hundreds of columns need to be cleaned in  the raw data. Each part of them is with the similar structure. For the analysis, I need to combine all the parts into a total one with the same colnames.

However, I really don't know how to do it with both variables and characters. Should I use !! ?

```r
Q14_1 <- Q14 %>% select(province, ends_with("open_1"))
colnames(Q14_1) <- c("province", paste0("A", 1:11))

Q14_2 <- Q14 %>% select(province, ends_with("open_2"))
colnames(Q14_2) <- c("province", paste0("A", 1:11))

Q14_3 <- Q14 %>% select(province, ends_with("open_3"))
colnames(Q14_3) <- c("province", paste0("A", 1:11))

Q14_4 <- Q14 %>% select(province, ends_with("open_4"))
colnames(Q14_4) <- c("province", paste0("A", 1:11))

Q14_bind <-bind_rows(Q14_1, Q14_2, Q14_3, Q14_4)
```

Is there a simple way to address this issue?

Thanks to Dr Parfait.

### His code works!

```r
df_list <- lapply(paste0("open_", 1:20), function(i) 
  setNames(select(Q14, province, ends_with(i)), 
           c("province", paste0("A", 1:11)))
)
```

df_list %>% bind_rows()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `lapply` to build a list of data frames for `bind_rows` at end and use `setNames` as right-hand version of `colnames()<-`:

```
df_list <- lapply(paste0("open_", 1:4), function(i) 
                       setNames(select(Q14, province, ends_with(i)), 
                                c("province", paste0("A", 1:11)))
           )

Q14_bind <- bind_rows(df_list)
```

Comment: Does this works for you? It raises an error for me.

Comment: Whoops! Forgot the data frame, `Q14`. Avoid using pipes inside `lapply` and `for` loops.